# How to initialize the camera correctly in Windows 8?

Tags: javascript, windows, camera, winjs

I am trying to initialize the camera on windows 8. I have enabled the webcam capability in the project and on my windows 8 device as well.

Here is my code:

```
var dialog = new Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();
var aspectRatio = { width: 1, height: 1 };

dialog.photoSettings.croppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
dialog.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo).done(function (file) {
    if (file) {
        editPreviewPicture(file);
        mainApp.pictureAccept('control');
    } else {

    }
}, function (e) {
    console.log("Error while opening camera: ", e);
});
```

On the line with 'captureFileAsync' I get the following error:

> Runtime-error JavaScript: Access Denied.

I have double checked everything that is needed, even downloaded the sample project to check the code and test the camera, everything worked fine in that project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The above function was in this code block:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/queue/view.html", {

    ready: function (element, options) {

    }
}
```

The problem is: The ready callback is for the DOM elements and not for javascript, so it was still processing aSync code, and WinJS can't handle multiple aSync processes properly. That's why I got 'Access denied'.

Now to fix this. You need to create a promise with a timeOut, like so:

```
WinJS.Promise.timeout(500).then(
    function (complete) {
        // Camera initialization / Other aSync code here
    },

    function (error) { }
 );
```

Hope this helps some people!